# jupyter contrib nbextension install --user fails

Tags: linux, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

On a conda installation installed via -c conda-forge, trying to install nbextensions via

```
jupyter contrib nbextension install  --user
```

Results in

```
    usage: jupyter-contrib [-h] [--debug] [--generate-config] [-y] [--log-level JupyterContribApp.log_level] [--config JupyterContribApp.config_file]                    [extra_args [extra_args ...]]
jupyter-contrib: error: argument --user: expected one argument
```

Did the procedure change recently?

Answer (score 1):

1. `pip3 install jupyter_nbextensions_configurator`
2. `jupyter nbextensions_configurator enable --user`
3. `jupyter notebook --ip=192.168.10.169 --no-browser --allow-root`
4. `pip3 install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions`
5. `jupyter contrib nbextension install --user`

Answer (score 0):

I know how to solve it.

For Win10, add "-" to:

```
jupyter-contrib-nbextension install --user
```